# Open URL followed by second URL

Tags: android, url

I need to open the URL followed by another in order to remove the previous URL for viewing. The action is required in-lieu of closing the browser tab.

The first URL is opening and the second one is no where to be seen. Where I am going wrong?

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL_STRING); 
    //modified the URL_STRING for security
    URL_STRING = "https://myserver.com/action";
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent1.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "toto");
    startActivity(intent1);

    //SystemClock.sleep(1000);

    String POST_URL = "http://www.google.com";
    uri = Uri.parse(POST_URL);
    final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent2.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "toto");
```

Have even tried to put a sleep with varying values. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this to load two URls in the external browser.

Declare these variables as global variables.

```
int count = 0;
Runnable runnable=null;
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then call this method to load the Url in browser.

```
  public void goToBrowser() {
    final Uri[] uri = new Uri[1];
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            switch (count) {
                case 0:
                    String URL_STRING = "https://myserver.com/action";
                    uri[0] = Uri.parse(URL_STRING);
                    //modified the URL_STRING for security
                    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri[0]);
                    intent1.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "toto");
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    String POST_URL = "http://www.google.com";
                    uri[0] = Uri.parse(POST_URL);
                    final Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri[0]);
                    intent2.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "toto");
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }

            if (count++ <= 1){
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }

        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

Comment: worked like charm.. Thank you. Got the mistake of not using startActivity on intent2. Also combining the wait activity. with 2000 ms it is perfectly working.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)